# How do I create a loop in VisualStudio with a set time between each activation?

Tags: c#

I was wondering how to make a loop in VisualStudio. I am able to make a while loop with this code:

```
int i = 0;
while (i<1)
{
    //event
}
```

However, I wanted to add a pause between each loop, so when //event is complete, it pauses for 3 seconds before repeating, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, not a programming language.

Comment: If its not a ui thread use Thread.Sleep(3000);...assuming C#

Comment: Use a timer instead of a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a console program. It shows one of many possibilities. If this does not satisfy your requirements then perhaps the requirements need clarification. Note that since this is a console program I am using an AutoResetEvent to cause the program to wait until WorkDone has the value 3. Your TimerCallback can do whatever needs to be done and will execute every 3 seconds.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace SO42323314
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WorkToDo ToDo = new WorkToDo();
            Timer ticker = new Timer(TimerCallback, ToDo, 0, 3000);
            ToDo.are.WaitOne();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This will be called every time the interval occurs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ToDoObject"></param>
        static void TimerCallback(object ToDoObject)
        {
            WorkToDo ToDo = ToDoObject as WorkToDo;
            Console.WriteLine(ToDo.WorkDone);
            ++ToDo.WorkDone;
            if (ToDo.WorkDone > 3)
                ToDo.are.Set(); // signal the AutoResetEvent
        }
    }

    class WorkToDo
    {
        public int WorkDone = 0;
        // initialize the AutoResetEvent to not signaled
        public AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }
}
```